# Tinymce - how to save off partial undo stack to restore later?

Tags: tinymce

We have product that has multiple instances of tinyMce, think of a sequences of essay questions. We create / destroy the mce instance when we move from question to question.
Users would like to be able to perform undo when returning to a previous question.
I have looked at the undomanager, the API is not clear how one might save / restore the undo stack.

I set a breakpoint at the change event and saved off the "lastlevel" property and used undomanager.add to give that back to the editor but this did not seem to work.
The API is not clear what is passed to add function.